# Would mathematics be different if not written one-dimensionally?

Tags: soft-question

Mathematics is written one-dimensionally, using symbols that make sense when put together on a line. The 2d sheets of paper that we use don't have enough room to write mathematics two-dimensionally. As a result, most symbols in mathematics are operations involving two objects (or one object acting on another object) and many mathematical concepts seem to depend on this fact (non-commutativity, left/right action).

> **Question:** Would mathematics be different for 4d beings writing on 3d sheets of paper? For example, can it make sense (for them) to extend the notion of left/right action to up/down?

Comment: I would say that mathematics is written 2-dimensionally:-)

Comment: The question is funny and thought-provoking, but how could we, 3-dimensional beings, answer it? Furthermore, let us quote from the rules of SE sites: *"Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."*

Comment: As for the "left/right" actions, I'd say there are no other natural possibilities since with $a,b$ you can form only two objects that depend *only* on $a,b$ in a given order: namely the ordered pairs, $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$. You can call the corresponding notions right/left, up/down, female/male, ... but the essence won't change.

Comment: @Qfwfq: I believe the OP has in mind operations not with 2, but with more arguments.

Comment: For example, what about the "ordered pairs" $\binom{a}{b}$ and $\binom{b}{a}$?

Comment: @Neal: you can denote them as you like, but there is still exactly two of them

Comment: (Actually, my comment fits better about functions of two arguments rather than actions. For actions of $G$ on $X$, what you have to give is exactly one element $g\,:\,G$, one $x\,:\, X$, and the choice between "homomorphism" and "anti-homomorphism")

Comment: @AlexM. Although it might be hard, I think that 3d beings can find convincing arguments to answer this question.

Comment: @Qfwfq: It seems that the very notion of homomorphism is a one-dimensional notion ;)

Comment: E.g., "right" matrix multiplication makes more sense as "on-top-of" matrix multiplication, given the way it works.

Comment: And, despite comments that claim that mathematics is inherently 1-D, due to someone's formal notion of "proof", ... after some decades of thinking about it, the allegedly mandatory "logical linearity" of mathematics is quite often a needless impediment to understanding. Many useful human constructs are not linear... but, instead, e.g., "searchable".

Comment: @paulgarrett: A 4d being would use cubic ($n \times n\times n$) matrices and there are many more ways of multiplying them.

Comment: @Vigod, I'd claim that "ways of multiplying <whatever>" is not necessarily relevant, since I would also claim that such notational devices are _narrative_ for more instrinsic underlying mathematical processes/procedures. That is, I do _not_ think that mathematics consists of mysterious operations on symbols,... but that symbols and operations are a way of talking about mathematics.

Comment: @paul garrett: Indeed, the logic of a proof maybe resembles more a tree than a "linear" thing

Comment: The apparent necessity of left/right actions is sneaking in by assuming our only choice is an order, which is 1D automatically. Arguably the 'linear' parts of math stem from time, since function composition represents joining operations temporally (e.g. group actions). In fields that get away from "ordered processing" higher-dimensional structures/languages appear more often. I'm surprised no one has mentioned higher-dimensional algebra (all but named in the question) or diagrammatic algebras, where the points about up/down actions and the constraints of linear notation are well appreciated.

Comment: @vigod in Physics there is the concept of PEPS (projected entangled pair states) which indeed, to be written nicely requires a two dimensional notation. Indeed a sort of contraction on matrices up/down/left/right

Comment: But all math is not written in 2D. What about all the nice stuff people do with diagram algebras (and $2$-categories and so on)?

Comment: My (admittedly naive) understanding is that the fundamental 'one-dimensionality' of the way we do mathematics is not based on our depiction or communication of it, but the fact that we develop a *sequence* of thoughts or statements, where each relies on the ones preceding it. Putting things like notation and the way the *content* of a (mathematical) statement is expressed aside, logic deduction itself is a fundamentally one-dimensional business. Not that I had any idea what 2-dimensional reasoning could be, though...

Comment: Exact. Exposition of mathematical thoughts, in particular, notations and graphic formalism, can gain, and does, from the opportunities offered by 2D or 3D graphics, and by motion, colors etc. But formally maths remains a matter of *finite chains of deductions*, which perfectly fits in a 1D structure, like e.g. a Turing machine.

Comment: I can't leave an answer, so here's  a comment.  In advanced math things called commutative diagrams can compress hundreds of function equalities that if written in textual terms would be incomprehensible, but when written in the more natural visual diagram form, are quite elegant and relatively easy to understand and remember.  So we do math in both text and visual form already.

Answer (score 13):

The fact that math is "written" one dimensionally has, I would say, little to do with the information we convey when writing.  It is written linearly because (1) our eyes have a single point of focus, and we can only move that point-of-focus in a 1-dimensional path; and (2) our input processing tends to be synchronous, not asynchronous.  The ideas in mathematics are very very seldom one-dimensional. We have become very good at conveying complex, multi-dimensional ideas with the tools we have.  So no, I don't think it is really significant.

Is there a correlation, i.e. if we were creatures that had multi-dimensional input capabilities, would mathematics be different?  Likely parts would have developed faster or more fully.  Development of good notation, e.g. arabic numerology, has always sped development, but not changed the underlying mathematics, and I would say the same would be true of developing multi-dimensional modes of communication.

But I would say mathematics is mathematics and is independent of the technology of communication.

Comment: I'm not completely convinced of the sentence "Development of good notation, e.g. arabic numerology, has always sped development, but not changed the underlying mathematics". Do you really think that it would be possible to develop something like Galois theory for equations using Greek numerology? Or homological algebra without 
using the arrow notation for functions?

Comment: Absolutely don't disagree with you.  But I must add, I am still astounded at some of the mathematics that actually _was_ discovered by some of these guys, even sometimes without arabic numerology.

Answer (score 9):

This should be a comment, but I do not know how to put an image there. Some commutative diagrams in homological algebra are in fact depicted "3-dimensionally" (or, at least, using perspective in order to simulate 3-dimensionality).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the main tool of mathematicians is, not a pen or keyboard or other writing tools, but imagination and image-ination. That is, mathematicians think in images, and then maybe in images of images, etc. Of course, images in mathematics are abstract (a bit like those in abstract painting) and concentrated (a bit like those in poetry). Symbols can also be considered images. E.g., when we say "let $X$ denote a separable Banach space", we may think of the concrete 3D or 2D space as an immediate instantiation/source of the symbol $X$. A mathematical formula is a concentrated image of a piece of mathematical text, and it appears that mathematicians of yore did use rather long pieces of text in place of our compact formulas -- which are much easier to grasp, visually and mentally. It further appears that the main original source of image-ination is visual images. Our vision is a very powerful tool. Yet, we can discern, I guess, maybe $10^4\times10^4$ pixels, at most, with our 2D retinas. One might then suppose that 4D mathematicians would be able to discern  $10^4\times10^4\times10^4$ pixels, $10^4$ times as many as we can, with their 3D retinas. Also, their 4D brains would presumably be much, much more powerful than ours. So, they would be able to build much better and more complicated images. Thus, whereas mathematics may be objectively one and the same in our 3D world and their 4D one, one can imagine/image-ine that our most advanced mathematics of today would look to 4D mathematicians as their preschool-level math.

Comment: I don't think in images about most of the mathematics I do. I guess I am not a mathematician... :'(

Comment: @AsafKaragila : But then, how do you think about mathematics? In symbols and formulas? But I think symbols and formulas are images too, as I have now tried to explain.

Comment: Yes, it's more akin to symbols and formulas, but it's not that. I just work with the basic statements until I grok them enough to just understand. And no, formulas and symbols are definitely not pictures. I think about also don't think about symbols and formulas in their symbolic form. I think about their semantic meaning. When you think about the word "chair" you think about the abstract object "word" and the meaning "chair", not the literal letters making it in English.

Comment: I never said that all images are pictures. Of course, most of the images, in mathematics, are not pictures. We talk about images of objects (elements or sets) under a mapping. When we talk about meanings of words, what are they -- other than images of words under a map (or more general binary relation) into real objects or images of real objects? The point here is that meanings are images as well, aren't they? Otherwise, what is the meaning of "meaning"? Also, vice versa, words are images of real objects or images under the inverse binary relation.

Comment: No. I disagree with that. If you start saying arbitrarily that anything you think about is an image, then might as well image image image image. Image, image? Image Image image...

Comment: I did not say that everything is an image, and I don't think so. However, you talked about meanings. What do you actually mean by a "meaning" other than an image of a certain kind? Also, you said you "just work with the basic statements". But how? In what terms do you think about math? That was unclear to me in your comment.

Comment: You know that you're trying to get an answer that a lot of research is being put into. Right? It's ineffable. You just have to accept that other people have other ways of thinking and understanding things. You understand things through a concept you describe as "image". I don't understand that concept like this. Whether or not we think about things the same is a whole other question, and even if not, what is it that goes through my head when I'm thinking is also entirely indescribable. It's just thoughts. They are more literal than imagery, but that does not mean it's "images of words".

Comment: "Undescribable" is fine with me. I just tried to describe, obviously imperfectly, the "undescribable".

Comment: Yes, of course you did. I'm just pointing out that I think that we think about things in completely different ways. And your claim that "mathematicians think in images" might come from not knowing how other mathematicians think, and thinking that they think the same as you (that being said, I do know that a lot of mathematicians do claim to think in a geometric and imagery based way, so you're certainly not the exception to the rule, but it's also very unclear to me what is the actual rule, if such rule exists).

Comment: Basically, I tried to understand how you think about math.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know how I think about math. Maybe that's why I often do it better when I mix small to moderate amounts of alcohol into the equation.

Comment: It appears that the thing that you do know about your thinking about math is that you don't think about math in images.

Comment: Yes, but reality is constructive and LEM does not hold. So knowing that it is not something doesn't mean that I know something positive about it. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Non-Constructive (Disappointing) Answer:** No you don't get anything else by letting your language be two-dimensional. This is because any rigorously-defined 2D language must be *a priori* defined in the 1D language of normal mathematics/logic. That means you cannot express anything extra in the 2D language -- though you might express the same things in a more natural or insightful manner. For analogous reasons you don't get anything new by using a 3D language.

**Example:** Double categories (taken from [this MathExchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2139586/trouble-understanding-an-example-of-a-double-category-that-is-not-a-2-category/2139651#2139651))

> An object in this category is a pair of sets and a map between them. Write $(A \to B)$ for example.
>
> Usually a morphism $f$ in a category has only one range $Dom(f)$ and codomain $Cod(f)$ assigned to it. In a double category there are two flavours of each for every morphism. A morphism in this category is a commutative square like this. . . .
>
> $A \ \to \  B$
>
> $\downarrow  \ \ \ \ \ \ \downarrow$
>
> $C \ \to \  D$
>
> The 'vertical' domain and codomain are $Dom_{|} = (A \to B)$ and $Cod_| = (C \to D)$
>
> The 'horizontal' domain and codomain are $Dom_-=(A \to C)$ and $Cod_- =(B \to D)$
>
> There are two 'vertical' and 'horizontal' notions of composition , call them $\circ_|$ and $\circ_-$. But we can only compose two morphisms using $\circ_|$ for example if the corresponding vertical domains match up. What this means is the bottom row of the first matches the top row of the second.
>
> We compose  vertically by putting the first on top of the second to get a tall rectangle. The corners of the rectangle form a new square. That square is the vertical composition.
>
> Likewise two squares can only be composed horizontally if the right column of the first matches the left column of the second. We compose  horizontally by putting the first left of the second to get a long rectangle. The corners of the rectangle form a new square. That square is the horizontal composition.
>
> It can occur that two morphisms may be composable horizontally but not vertically or vice versa.

Perhaps this satisfies your intuition for what a 2D version of a category should be? But observe we had no trouble defining it in normal 1D mathematics. So while the 2D perspective it might help our intuition it does not add anything in terms of the strength of the language.

**Example:** Proof Grids

> Suppose $\mathcal L$ is our universe of symbols. In 1D maths a proof is a string of $N$ symbols. That means a map $\{0,1,2, \ldots, N\} \to \mathcal L$. Suppose we want a 2D proof to be a grid  of $M \times M$ symbols (some symbols can be blank). That means a map $\{0,1,2, \ldots, M\}^2 \to \mathcal L$
>
> But recall the sets $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N^2$ have the same cardinality.
>   This induces an isomorphism between the classes of 1D and 2D proofs. Thus every 2D proof can already be expressed as a 1D proof.

**Example:** Digital images

> Every (two dimensional) computer image is stored as a (one dimensional) binary sequence.

Comment: Your arguments apply for mathematics that can be written two-dimensionally on a 2d sheet of paper. This is very different (and much more constraining) from what I asked, namely mathematics that can be written two-dimensionally on a 3d sheet of paper.

Comment: Granted. Though I believe (but have yet to write down in full) that all my examples scale up to any finite dimension. For example we can define a triple category whose morphisms are cubes, and each cube has three domains and three codomains corresponding to pairs of sides of the cube. Likewise we can encode a 3D proof using a bijection from $\mathbb N^3 \to \mathbb N$.